# Norm of particular continuous linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T: C[a,b] \to C[a,b]$ be continuous linear transformation such that 
$$
(T(f))(x) = x \int\limits_a^b f(u) ~du.
$$

Considering the following definition 
$$
||T|| := \sup_{f \in B_{C[a,b]}} ||T(f)||,
$$

I want to prove that 
$$
||T|| = |b|(b-a).
$$

I've been able to prove $(\leq)$ because 
$$
||T(f)|| = \max_{x \in [a,b]} \Big| x \int\limits_a^b f(u) ~du \Big| \leq \Big( \max_{x \in [a,b]} |x| \int\limits_a^b  ~du \Big) ||f(u)||_{\infty},
$$
but I'm yet to find a convenient lower bound to lead the way for $(\geq)$.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $||T(f)|| \leq ||T|| $, for any $f$ with $||f||_{\infty}=1$, then take $f_0$ to be the constant function $1$:

$$
||T(f_0)|| = \max_{x \in [a,b]} \Big| x \int\limits_a^b 1 ~du \Big| = \max_{x \in [a,b]} |x|(b-a) = |b|(b-a)
$$
So $|b|(b-a)$ is a lower bound for $||T||$ as well.

Answer (score 0):

Take the constant function $f=1$ which has norm $1$. Then $\|Tf\|=|b|(b-a)$.